# Will Ubuntu non-carrier phones be available?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

I live in India, where CDMA technology (where you can't change your SIM card, and you have to stick with one service provider once you buy the phone) is not popular. GSM is the general trend. I am really really keen on buying an Ubuntu phone. But so far, i have only heard of phones shipping Ubuntu along with a carrier (which i believe is the same as the service provider), and i'm wondering if canonical will ship Ubuntu phones, without any carriers, in which you can insert your own SIM card? I've wanted the Ubuntu phone to be my first smartphone. Now, if Ubuntu phone is going to release in April, 2014, and that too, without GSM capability, i don't know if I should wait for it to release. I want Ubuntu Phone to be my first smartphone, but if the wait isn't really worth it, should i go ahead with another phone now?

Comment: First we need a phone-manufacturer to ship Ubuntu-phone-os with. Why not write to micromax, lava or xolo to adopt Ubuntu on their next flagship phone? After all they are very successful with android in India.They could do the same for Ubuntu. Although right now, Ubuntu-touch-os is still very early development stage. I think if Ubuntu-phone makes a successful entry in the market they will bring it into production.

Comment: Fingers crossed! I like your idea about contacting these companies, though i wonder if they'll pay any heed at all! I've written to XOLO, and will probably write to the other two, too! Anyway, do you happen to have any idea as to how easy it is to unlock these carrier locked phones?Its quite easy to get a phone into india if you have some relative in the US, but i don't know how easy it is to unlock the phone!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ubuntu Edge website (Which I think you are referring to), the Ubuntu phone is unlocked.  As such, it is open to any carrier.  ALL these phones will be non-carrier specific.  Now the problem here is that I doubt that the project is going to go ahead, because funding does seem insignificant.  Anyway, you can read more up on the Ubuntu phone here:

http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge

Comment: Why -1 I answered his question?

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 4 (which you can buy unlocked directly by Google) is capable of being flashed to run the Ubuntu Touch OS. But that's supposedly risky as it may brick your phone and is only recommended for developers. As of right now, I'm not aware of any phone that you can buy with Ubuntu Touch pre-installed, unlocked or not. People may be talking about it like it's already out, but it's still in development.

Comment: Hmm, thanks a lot for the answer! But isn't a stable Ubuntu Touch OS going to release for Nexus phones in October, along with Ubuntu 13.10? I thought that was how Canonical has planned the release! Please correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: Apparently that's the plan, but it's not carved in stone